# JSSOR jquery and jquery.min.js on Responsive PHP page

Tags: php, slider, jssor

Slider working great [here](http://auction.cruisefortroops.org), but when in a smaller format on a phone as an example, the menu will not roll back up for other items or possibly not drop down for some dropdown items.

Saw one article "bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min,js, and ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js not resolving" but did not see anything there to help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to use the code found at link http://docs.sitefinity.com/for-developers-avoid-conflicts-when-loading-multiple-versions-of-jquery
below wrapper and remove one of the references to "bootstrap.min.js".